# Handling exception thrown inside creation of ReactiveCommand in ReactiveUI way

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, reactiveui

I just started to learn ReactiveUI, I have read and launched ReactiveDemo (https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/ https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/master/samples/getting-started).

I noticed that when URL to a found project is missing, the NugetDetailsViewModel.ProjectUrl variable gets `null` and when user tries to open project site, the NullReferenceException is thrown.

I tried to use `OpenPage.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe()` to handle this error, but it didn't work.

So my question is, how to do it ReactiveUI way? I know I can write `try-catch` block around `Process.Start()`, but it's not cool, right? :)

My (edited a little bit) code of NugetDetailsViewModel.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace ReactiveDemo
{
    // This class wraps out NuGet model object into a ViewModel and allows
    // us to have a ReactiveCommand to open the NuGet package URL.
    public class NugetDetailsViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private readonly IPackageSearchMetadata _metadata;
        private readonly Uri _defaultUrl;

        public NugetDetailsViewModel(IPackageSearchMetadata metadata)
        {
            _metadata = metadata;
            _defaultUrl = new Uri("https://git.io/fAlfh");

            OpenPage = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
            {
                Process.Start(ProjectUrl.ToString()); // exception is thrown here when ProjectUrl is null
            });

            OpenPage.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(error =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }); // doesn't work
        }

        public Uri IconUrl => _metadata.IconUrl ?? _defaultUrl;
        public string Description => _metadata.Description;
        public Uri ProjectUrl => _metadata.ProjectUrl;
        public string Title => _metadata.Title;

        // ReactiveCommand allows us to execute logic without exposing any of the 
        // implementation details with the View. The generic parameters are the 
        // input into the command and it's output. In our case we don't have any 
        // input or output so we use Unit which in Reactive speak means a void type.
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OpenPage { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked when I edited NugetDetailsView.xaml.cs, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to solve problems like this.

`if (ViewModel.ProjectUrl != null)
                {
                    this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
                        viewModel => viewModel.OpenPage,
                        view => view.openButton).DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
                }`

Comment: I don't know the correct answer to your question, but I have a feeling that the `ThrownExceptions` probably only works when you use the `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable` helper.  Why don't you just do a null check inside the `Action`?

Comment: how do you invoke the command?